# How can i show Data from mysql specific month

Tags: php, mysql

```html
$query = mysql_query(
         "SELECT id, BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,DateTime FROM `order`
         WHERE DateTime="2015 AND 08""; LIMIT $start, $per_page"
         ) 
or die(mysql_error());
```

I'm trying to make the query to show specific month and year.

Comment: how does your table look? what does the query show as it is now?

Comment: @hoijui sintax error it shows

Comment: My answer did not work for you?

Comment: Though already accept hahaha

Comment: @MohdFadli Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's Built-in `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions like:

```
SELECT `id`, `BuyerName`,`BuyerEmail`,`TransactionID`,`DateTime`   
FROM `order` WHERE YEAR(DATE(`DateTime`))=2015 AND MONTH(DATE(`DateTime`)) = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column has a datatype of [`date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) you can use a range of dates for your criteria in a [**`Sargable`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) way

```
SELECT id, BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,DateTime
 FROM `order` 
WHERE DateTime >='01-08-2015' 
AND  DateTime <= '31-08-2015'
```

For [`datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) you can write it as

```
SELECT id, BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,DateTime
 FROM `order` 
WHERE DateTime >='01-08-2015 00:00:00' 
AND  DateTime <= '31-08-2015 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

if type of column is datetime then try this

```
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT id, BuyerName, BuyerEmail, TransactionID, `DateTime` 
    FROM `order` 
    WHERE YEAR(DATE(`DateTime`)) = 2015 AND MONTH(DATE(`DateTime`)) = 8
    LIMIT $start, $per_page
") or die(mysql_error());
```

or simply

```
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT id, BuyerName, BuyerEmail, TransactionID, `DateTime` 
    FROM `order` 
    WHERE `DateTime` LIKE '2015-08-%'
    LIMIT $start, $per_page
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time_you_want_to_choose = strtotime('previous month');

$ym = date('Y-m', $time_you_want_to_choose);

$query = mysql_query("
          SELECT `id`, `BuyerName`, `BuyerEmail` , `TransactionID`, `DateTime` 
          FROM `order` 
          WHERE `DateTime` like '$ym%'
          LIMIT $start, $per_page
         ");
```